# Fade in each path of SVG one after another

Tags: jquery, css, svg, svg-animate

I have an SVG with lots and lots of paths like this:

```
<svg version="1.1"
     id="svg2" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="411.174px"
     viewBox="-468.068 410.987 400 411.174" enable-background="new -468.068 410.987 400 411.174" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="layer1" inkscape:label="Capa 1" inkscape:groupmode="layer">
    <g id="g3341" transform="translate(-5498.7634,510.10841)" inkscape:label="completebody:x0.00:x0.00:x0.00:x0.00:x0.00:x0.00">

            <g id="g63451" transform="translate(-5600.6166,-1161.19179528)" inkscape:label="completebody:z180.00:y180.00:x0.00:z0.00:y0.00:x0.00">

                <path class="path" id="path63453" inkscape:label="Face:4354" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#B2B2B2" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
                M10775.398,1084.903l-14.83,8.177l7.673,1.257L10775.398,1084.903z"/>

                <path class="path" id="path63455" inkscape:label="Face:3499" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B2B2B2" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
                M10885.204,1082.795l-5.618-2.201l6.066,7.177L10885.204,1082.795z"/>

                <path class="path" id="path63457" inkscape:label="Face:3527" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#B2B2B2" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
                M10885.204,1082.795l0.448,4.976l7.603,4.008L10885.204,1082.795z"/>
```

....

I was wondering if there was a way of how to fade in each path opacity 0 to 1, one after another, not sure how exactly it could be done, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you could do it with SMIL or CSS animations. With SMIL you'd begin subsequent animations on the end of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Just done exactly this by looping through each `<path>` with jQuery

```
var gapBetweenEach = 10;
var speedOfFade = 150;

$('.yourPathClass')).each(function(i, path){
   $(path).delay(gapBetweenEach * i).fadeIn(speedOfFade, function(){
  //Done animating this path        
    });
})
```

You'll have to add…

```
style="display:none"
```

…to each of you `<paths>`, for the `fadeIn` to work

Comment: this doesn't work in Edge for me. works on other browsers. it appears flashy, not fading in.